# Question based on binomial theorem and complex numbers.

Tags: complex-numbers, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Prove that $$C_1+C_5+ C_9+... =\frac{1}{2}\bigg(2^{n-1}+2^{n/2}\sin\frac{n\pi}{4}\bigg)$$

Here $C_i$ denotes the binomial coefficient $\binom ni$.

I tried to solve this problem by using de Moivre's theorem but could not proceed further.

Comment: What does $C_i$ represent?

Comment: They are the binomial coefficients. $C_i=(^n_i)$

Comment: I will point out that some sums of this type are mentioned in Wikipedia article on binomial coefficients - in the section [Multisections of sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Multisections_of_sums) - however without a proof. (I will also add link to [the current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Binomial_coefficient&oldid=868366879#Multisections_of_sums).)

Comment: And you can also find several posts on this site which are about *similar* sums (although perhaps not the same) - looking at the solutions there might help you. For example: [Find the value $\binom {n}{0} + \binom{n}{4} + \binom{n}{8} + \cdots $, where $n$ is a positive integer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2404878), [Finding $\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{3} + \binom{n}{6} + \ldots $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/875153) or [How do I count the subsets of a set whose number of elements is divisible by 3? 4?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/918)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3016886/calculate-sum-limits-n-0-infty-fracx3n3n/3016891#3016891

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1+x)^n=C_0+C_1x+C_2x^2+...+C_nx^n\\\implies(1+1)^n=2^n=C_0+C_1+...+C_n\\\implies(1-1)^n=0=C_0-C_1+...+(-1)^nC_n\\\implies(1+i)^n=2^{n/2}e^{n\pi/4}=(C_0-C_2+C_4...)+i(C_1-C_3+C_5...)\\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 2^{n/2}\sin n\pi/4=C_1-C_3+C_5...$

$\frac{2^n-0}2+2^{n/2}\sin n\pi/4=2(C_1+C_5...)$